# How to use PostAsJsonAsync with fields containing arrays in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

```
@inject HttpClient Http 
@page "/"
<button class="checkout" @onclick="() => createOrder()">Place Order</button>
@code {

public List<CartToSendItems> items { get; set; } = new List<CartToSendItems>();
public class CartToSend
{
    public Guid customerId { get; set; }
    public List<CartToSendItems> items = new List<CartToSendItems>();
}
public class CartToSendItems
{
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
}
public async Task createOrder()
{
    CartToSend body = new CartToSend();
    body.customerId = Guid.Parse("68e03745-e4a2-480f-9f39-eac36aa1ddcd");
    body.items = GetItems();
    var jsonBody = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<CartToSend>(body);
    Console.WriteLine(jsonBody.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("items: " + body.items.Count.ToString());
    var httpResponse = await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<CartToSend>("http://localhost:1337/orders/create", body);
}
protected List<CartToSendItems> GetItems() {
    List<CartToSendItems> ret = new List<CartToSendItems>();
    CartToSendItems item1 = new CartToSendItems();
    item1.productId = 1;
    item1.qty = 2;
    CartToSendItems item2 = new CartToSendItems();
    item2.productId = 4;
    item2.qty = 2;
    ret.Add(item1);
    ret.Add(item2);
    return ret;
}
}
```

This is actually just sending the customerId and the items is being ignored. So the backend server is just receiving: { customerId: '68e03745-e4a2-480f-9f39-eac36aa1ddcd' }

What is the correct way to perform this action ? thanks in advance

**EDIT: Example edited for a better understanding as raw.**

My consoles outputs:

{"customerId":"68e03745-e4a2-480f-9f39-eac36aa1ddcd"}

items: 2

NodeJS Backend log:

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/1c18c737-e806-4770-ac13-8bd6e6c821b3

For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

Debugger attached.

GET / 304 466.248 ms - -

GET /stylesheets/main.css 304 1.439 ms - -

OPTIONS /orders/create 204 0.463 ms - 0

Missing Fields
{ customerId: '68e03745-e4a2-480f-9f39-eac36aa1ddcd' }

POST /orders/create 403 18.247 ms - 18

Comment: declare 'items' as a property : public List<CartToSendItems> items { get; set; }

Comment: hi what does the API on http://localhost:1337/orders/create look like? and does the GetItems() return a list with items in it?

Comment: @yasseros, I placed public List<CartToSendItems> items { get; set; }  = new List<CartToSendItems>(); after the @@code and the result is the same. but thanks !

Comment: @DavidMasterson GetItems() will return a list of CartToSendItems type

Comment: but does it actually? Is it producing a list or an empty list or a null? Also at the API end you would need something like  Create([FromBody] CartToSend Cart) which would deserialize the information into a CartToSend object.

Comment: It's producing a list with many items of type CartToSendItems, @DavidMasterson .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this method :

```
public class CartToSend
{
    public Guid customerId { get; set; }
    public List<CartToSendItems> items = new List<CartToSendItems>();
}
```

by :

```
public class CartToSend
        {
            public Guid customerId { get; set; }
            public List<CartToSendItems> items { get; set; } = new List<CartToSendItems>();
        }
```

'items' was delclared as field that why it does not get serialized

Comment: This is the right answer. In your edited code you are missing the {get;set;}  for the items list INSIDE the CartToSend class.  You do have the structure right for the UNUSED items on line 6

Comment: to be clear the line with the error is line 10

Comment: Thanks @yasseros !

Comment: Thanks @DavidMasterson !

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is the problem your class  CartToSend  is describing  the list as a field not a property  so it is not being serialised.

change

```
public List<CartToSendItems> items = new List<CartToSendItems>();
```

to

```
public List<CartToSendItems> items {get;set;} = new List<CartToSendItems>();
```

Comment: I did it already. Check the comments to @yasseros just one bellow yours. It's was exactly as you wrote. The result remains the same.

Comment: can you please update the question with the code you are currently using and the API code

Comment: Ok, @david-masteson ! and I performed a full edit